# How can I animate the following graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I've drawn this for my calc 1 students so they can understand the definition of "La corde", basically I wanted to animate the following graph :

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=50mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns, snakes}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning, calc, decorations.text, angles, 
     quotes}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=4.75]
        \draw[smooth, ->] (0.8,0)--(4.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[smooth, ->] (1,-0.2)--(1,3.5) node[left] {$y$};
        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},scale=1.5]
        \filldraw[red!30!white, opacity=0.7] (1.7,0)--(1.7,0.879)--(1.5,0.845)--(1.5,0)--cycle;
        \draw[domain=1.1:2.1,blue, samples=900,scale=1,fill=white] plot(\x, {(1/7)*(\x-1)^3+(\x- 
        1)^2*ln(\x-1)+1});
        \draw[domain=1.3:1.9,blue!30!black, samples=900, <->,scale=1] plot(\x, {0.846+0.1412*(\x- 
        1.6)});
        \draw[dashed] (1.7,0)--(1.7,0.879) node[above, red] {$B'$};
        \draw[dashed] (1.5,0)--(1.5,0.845) node[above, red] {$A'$};
        \draw[magenta] (1.5,0.8445)--(1.7,0.874);
        \node[magenta, rotate=0] at (1.6,0.9) {$[A'B']$};
        \draw[dashed] (1.2,0)--(1.2,0.9367)--(0.665,0.9367)node[left, red] {$f(a)$};
        \draw[dashed] (2,0)--(2,8/7)--(0.665,8/7)node[left, red] {$f(b)$};
        \draw[dashed] (1.6,0)--(1.6,0.846)--(0.665,0.846)node[left=0.1cm, red] {$f(x_0)$};
        \filldraw[red] (0.665,0.9367)circle(0.01);
        \filldraw[red] (0.665,0.846)circle(0.01);
        \filldraw[red] (0.665,8/7)circle(0.01);
        \draw[thick, magenta] (2,8/7)--(1.2,0.9367) node[midway, above, rotate=30] {$[AB]$};
        \node[red, above] at (2,8/7) {$B$};
        \node[red, below] at (1.1,1.05) {$A$};
        \filldraw[red] (1.6,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$x_0$};
        \filldraw[red] (1.2,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$a$};
        \filldraw[red] (2,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$b$};
        \filldraw[red] (1.6-0.1,0)circle(0.01) node[above=0.2cm, left] {$x_0-\varepsilon$};
        \filldraw[red] (1.6+0.1,0)circle(0.01) node[above=0.2cm, right] {$x_0+\varepsilon$};
  \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
So my questions are :

1. How can I animate this by varying the parameter `\varepsilon`
2. Where to learn `animate` package ([the package documentation](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) wasn't enough)

And thank you :D !

**Edit :**
After checking some of the previous posts about animating a figure, I tried the following :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=5]
\draw[smooth, ->] (0.8,0)--(4.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[smooth, ->] (1,-0.2)--(1,3.5) node[left] {$y$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},scale=1.5]
\filldraw[red!30!white, opacity=0.7] (1.6+\i,0)--(1.6+\i,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})--((1.6-\i),{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--(1.6-\i,0)--cycle;
\draw[domain=1.1:2.08,blue, samples=900,scale=1,fill=white] plot(\x, {(1/7)*(\x-1)^3+(\x-1)^2*ln(\x-1)+1});
\draw[domain=1.3:1.9,blue!30!black, samples=900, <->,scale=1] plot(\x, {0.846+0.1412*(\x-1.6)});
\draw[dashed] (1.6-\i,0)--(1.6-\i,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--(0.665,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})node[left, red] {$f(a)$};
\draw[dashed] (1.6+\i,0)--(1.6+\i,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})--(0.665,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})node[left, red] {$f(b)$};
\draw[dashed] (1.6,0)--(1.6,0.846)--(0.665,0.846)node[left=0.1cm, red] {$f(x_0)$};
\filldraw[red] (0.665,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})circle(0.01);
\filldraw[red] (0.665,0.846)circle(0.01);
\filldraw[red] (0.665,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})circle(0.01);
\draw[thick, magenta] (1.6-\i,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--(1.6+\i,{1/7*((1.6+\i)-1)^3+((1.6+\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6+\i)-1)+1}) ;
\filldraw[red] (1.6,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$x_0$};
\filldraw[red] (1.2,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$a$};
\filldraw[red] (2,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$b$};
\filldraw[red] (1.6-0.1,0)circle(0.01) node[above=0.2cm, left] {$x_0-\varepsilon$};
\filldraw[red] (1.6+0.1,0)circle(0.01) node[above=0.2cm, right] {$x_0+\varepsilon$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

But an error occurred, and I couldn't fix it, for the instance fixing this error will easily let me animate my figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the error ! so basically it was the command that fills the drawing with red, here's the code and the result :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.375,0.4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=5]
\draw[smooth, ->] (0.8,0)--(4.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[smooth, ->] (1,-0.2)--(1,3.5) node[left] {$y$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},scale=1.5]
  \filldraw[red!30!white, opacity=0.7]
    (1.6+\i, 0)--
    (1.6+\i, {1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})--
    (1.6-\i, {1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--
    (1.6-\i, 0)--cycle;
\draw[domain=1.1:2.08,blue, samples=900,scale=1,fill=white] plot(\x, {(1/7)*(\x-1)^3+(\x-1)^2*ln(\x-1)+1});
\draw[domain=1.3:1.9,blue!30!black, samples=900, <->,scale=1] plot(\x, {0.846+0.1412*(\x-1.6)});
\draw[dashed] (1.6-\i,0)--(1.6-\i,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--(0.665,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})node[left, red] {$f(a)$};
\draw[dashed] (1.6+\i,0)--(1.6+\i,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})--(0.665,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})node[left, red] {$f(b)$};
\draw[dashed] (1.6,0)--(1.6,0.846)--(0.665,0.846)node[left=0.1cm, red] {$f(x_0)$};
\filldraw[red] (0.665,{1/7*((\i+1.6)-1)^3+((\i+1.6)-1)^2*ln((\i+1.6)-1)+1})circle(0.01);
\filldraw[red] (0.665,0.846)circle(0.01);
\filldraw[red] (0.665,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})circle(0.01);
\draw[thick, magenta] (1.6-\i,{1/7*((1.6-\i)-1)^3+((1.6-\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6-\i)-1)+1})--(1.6+\i,{1/7*((1.6+\i)-1)^3+((1.6+\i)-1)^2*ln((1.6+\i)-1)+1}) ;
\filldraw[red] (1.6,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$x_0$};
\filldraw[red] (1.6-\i,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$a$};
\filldraw[red] (1.6+\i,0)circle(0.01) node[below] {$b$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Using this in the animation package we get :
[image]

It worked perfectly !